how to enforce required properties when using a custom System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter
I'm trying to write a custom converter by following the sample factory pattern converter and also trying to enforce required properties as described here. I can find many examples of writing custom converters and many examples of defining required properties but I haven't found any examples where both are used together.
Take this TestClass that I'm deserializing with TestClassConverter:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace JsonContractsTest
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace JsonContractsTest
{
    public class TestClassConverter : JsonConverterFactory
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            return typeToConvert == typeof(TestClass);
        }

        public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            return new TestClassConverterInner(options);
        }

        private class TestClassConverterInner : JsonConverter<TestClass>
        {
            private JsonConverter<int> int32Converter { get; }

            public TestClassConverterInner(JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                this.int32Converter = (JsonConverter<int>)options.GetConverter(typeof(int));
            }

            public override TestClass? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                    throw new JsonException();

                TestClass obj = new TestClass();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                        return obj;

                    // get the property name
                    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                        throw new JsonException();

                    string? propertyName = reader.GetString();

                    // get the property value
                    reader.Read();
                    if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(nameof(TestClass.Value), propertyName))
                    {
                        obj.Value = this.int32Converter.Read(ref reader, typeof(int), options);
                    }
                }

                throw new JsonException();
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TestClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}

I deserialize a JSON string using this test console app:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace JsonContractsTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // doesn't contain a property named "value"
            string json = """{"notMapped":1}""";

            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
            {
                Converters =
                {
                    // JsonSerializer.Deserialize doesn't throw when using TestClassConverter
                    //new TestClassConverter(),
                },
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            };

            TestClass? test = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(json, options);
            Console.WriteLine(test?.ToString());
        }
    }
}

As expected, JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(json, options) throws JsonException when using default converters. If I uncomment //new TestClassConverter(), then JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(json, options) no longer throws any exception. How do I enforce [JsonRequired] when I use a custom converter?

You can use default type info to get required properties and check that all are present. Something along these lines:
// or create copy of options and remove the TestClassConverter
var requiredProps = JsonSerializerOptions.Default.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TestClass)).Properties
    .Where(p => p.IsRequired)
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

TestClass obj = new TestClass();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
    {
        if (requiredProps.Any())
        {
            throw new JsonException($"Missing required props: {string.Join(",", props)}");
        }

        return obj;
    }

    // ...
    requiredProps.Remove(propertyName);
    // ...
}


When deserialising a single object, this would work fine but when deserialising a large array of objects, this would create a new HashSet for every single object. Is this really how default converters enforce JsonRequired?

@ElGordo 1. you can use pooling for this to reduce the effect of allocations 2. as far as I can see - basically yes, but with more advanced approach using bit arrays - source, but have not dug too deep.
